# Use a localhost file on a url API - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel, api, url

Can we use a file who is stored on a localhost server, with an URL Api ??

The path for my localhost file is : `http://localhost/DPGF/dpgf.xls`

The API url link is :

`https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/view.do?url=http://link.to/file.xls&name=newName`

And i'm trying to do this :

`https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/view.do?url=http://localhost/DPGF/dpgf.xls&name=newName`

But this doesn't work for me.. so i don't know why or just that the API only supports real file links :(

Comment: no. localhost is reachable only from your machine.

Comment: localhost means exactly what it means, the file is hosted locally and the outside world does not have access to it through localhost "domain" which is an alias for a local IP 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

First of all localhost is only reachable from your own machine, server at sheet.zoho.com could not possibly have access to it, and even if it did there would still be problems with cross-origin access to the page.